# Processing generating a random amount of text

Tags: random, processing, draw

I am trying to generate some random text using processing, what I want is that everytime I press the mouse new text is generated and is displayed on the screen. As of now the text is simply generated than it gets removed due to the looping of draw() any way to fix this?

```
int click = 0;
void setup() {
String alfabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
size(1000,1000);
textSize(64);
textAlign(CENTER);

}
void draw() {
background(0);
if(click==1) {
click = 0;
genereren();
}
}
void genereren() {
String alfabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
int x = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i = i+1) {
float r = random(24);
if(r < 1) {
  r = r+1;
}
int d = int(r);
String EersteLetter = alfabet.substring(d-1,d);
if ( i <= 4) {
text(EersteLetter, 60+(x*3*i), 80);  
} 
if ( i <= 8) {
text(EersteLetter, 60+(x*3*i), 120);  
}
if ( i <= 12) {
text(EersteLetter, 60+(x*3*i), 160);  
}
if ( i <= 16) {
text(EersteLetter, 60+(x*3*i), 200);  
}
}
}
void mouseClicked() {
  click = 1;
}
```

Comment: You just need to "remember" the strings and draw them in draw(). Create a list of strings, append a new one too it every click, make draw loop through the list and output each text.

Comment: I've been trying to store it into an array first, than reading it but I cannot find a way to run the cycle only once. Would it be possible to store it in a separate void and than get that array into draw?

Answer (score 0):

try this example, if you click the mouse it will display or not, if you hold the mouse button you will freeze the current text.

```
boolean click = false;
void setup() {
  String alfabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
  size(1000, 1000);
  textSize(64);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  background(0);
}
void draw() {
  if (click) {
    genereren();
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    genereren();
  }
}

void genereren() {
  background(0);
  String alfabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
  int x = 10;
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i = i+1) {
    float r = random(24);
    if (r < 1) {
      r = r+1;
    }
    int d = int(r);
    String EersteLetter = alfabet.substring(d-1, d);
    if ( i <= 4) {
      text(EersteLetter, 60+(x*3*i), 80);
    } 
    if ( i <= 8) {
      text(EersteLetter, 60+(x*3*i), 120);
    }
    if ( i <= 12) {
      text(EersteLetter, 60+(x*3*i), 160);
    }
    if ( i <= 16) {
      text(EersteLetter, 60+(x*3*i), 200);
    }
  }
}
void mouseReleased() {
  clear();
}
void mouseClicked() {
  click=!click;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be just by not using the "background(0);", this way the text would stay for ever. Then you could add a button that runs a method whit the "background(0);" to erase all text.